# Why my API takes 2-3 seconds to proccess one request?

Tags: php, sql-server, nosql

I have problem with my API. I build API with lumen and used sql server for my DB. So this API has a function to insert a data. But before inserting data, my apps check the data if theres any data with same parameter is inserted.

The problem is everytime the request sent to my API, it takes 2-3 seconds to proccess. When i trace with my log, it shows when check duplicate data, it takes 1 second, and when saving data it takes 1 second.

Is there any suggestion for a better performance? i think about noSQL with php. Is it more powerfull rather than sql server?

For information, my DB used with multiple apps connect to it. Thanks

This is my code

```html
$getSameSppa = Sppa::where('nosppa', $SppaData->SPPA)
                ->whereNotNull('policyno')
                ->get();
        if($getSameSppa->count() > 0){
            $PolicyNo = $getSameSppa[0]->policyno;
                
            $return['data'] = array(
                'ID' => property_exists($SppaData, 'ID') ? $SppaData->ID:'',
                'SppaNo' => $SppaData->SPPA,
                'PolicyNo' => $PolicyNo
            );
            
            $return['response_code'] = env('BRI_RESPONSE_CODE_DUPLICATE','02');
            $return['message'] = 'SPPA sudah pernah disubmit';
            
            Facades\Log::info('SPPA sudah pernah disubmit', $return);
        }
        else{
            Facades\Log::info('SPPA belum pernah disubmit');
            
            // delete SPPA dengan nomor polis kosong
            Sppa::where('nosppa', $SppaData->SPPA)
                    ->whereNull('policyno')
                    ->delete();
            
            
            $nomorPolis = $this->_generate_policy_number($SppaData->MAKER_BRANCH_CODE, $SppaData->KODE_PRODUK, $SppaData->SPPA);
            Facades\Log::info('Generate nomor polis berhasil');
            
            try {
                $insertSppa = new Sppa();
                $insertSppa->nosppa = $SppaData->SPPA;
                $insertSppa->urutansppa = $SppaData->URUTAN_SPPA;
                $insertSppa->norekpinjaman = $SppaData->NOREK_PINJAMAN;
                $insertSppa->noreksimpanan = '';
                $insertSppa->kodeuker = sprintf('%05d', $SppaData->MAKER_BRANCH_CODE);
                $insertSppa->kodeproduk = $SppaData->KODE_PRODUK;
                $insertSppa->jenisproduk = $SppaData->JENIS_PRODUK;
                $insertSppa->tanggalentri = $SppaData->SPV_DATE;
                $insertSppa->periodeawal = $SppaData->PERIODE_MULAI_PERTANGGUNGAN;
                $insertSppa->periodeakhir = $SppaData->PERIODE_AKHIR_PERTANGGUNGAN;
                $insertSppa->tanggalrealisasipinjaman = $SppaData->TANGGAL_REALISASI_PINJAMAN;
                $insertSppa->jangkawaktupinjamanbulan = $SppaData->JANGKA_WAKTU_PINJAMAN_BULAN;
                $insertSppa->jangkawaktupinjamantahun = $SppaData->JANGKA_WAKTU_PINJAMAN_TAHUN;
                $insertSppa->loantypepinjaman = $SppaData->KODE_LOANTYPE;
                $insertSppa->namatertanggung = $SppaData->NAMA_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->alamattertanggung = $SppaData->ALAMAT_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->tanggallahir = $SppaData->TANGGAL_LAHIR_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->lokasiresiko = $SppaData->ALAMAT_RESIKO;
                $insertSppa->alamattempatusaha = $SppaData->ALAMAT_TEMPAT_USAHA;
                $insertSppa->notelp = $SppaData->NOMOR_HANDPHONE_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->email = $SppaData->EMAIL_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->noktp = $SppaData->NO_IDENTITAS_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->cif = $SppaData->CIF_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->cifpinjaman = $SppaData->CIF_PINJAMAN;
                $insertSppa->kodepos = $SppaData->KODEPOS_SIMPANAN;
                $insertSppa->kodeposresiko = $SppaData->KODEPOS_RESIKO;
                $insertSppa->kodepostempatusaha = $SppaData->KODEPOS_TEMPAT_USAHA;
                $insertSppa->policyno = $nomorPolis;
                $insertSppa->namaahliwaris = substr($SppaData->NAMA_AHLI_WARIS, 0, 49);
                $insertSppa->alamatahliwaris = $SppaData->ALAMAT_AHLI_WARIS;
                $insertSppa->notelpahliwaris = $SppaData->NOMOR_TELPON_AHLI_WARIS;
                $insertSppa->hubungan = $SppaData->HUBUNGAN_AHLI_WARIS;
                $insertSppa->tgl_terima_sppa = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                
                $saveSppa = $insertSppa->save();
                
                Facades\Log::info('Simpan SPPA berhasil');
            } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
                $return['data'] = array(
                    'ID' => property_exists($SppaData, 'ID') ? $SppaData->ID:'',
                    'SppaNo' => $SppaData->SPPA,
                    'PolicyNo' => ''
                );
                
                $return['message'] = 'Gagal simpan data SPPA';
                $return['exception'] = $ex->getMessage();
                
                $saveSppa = FALSE;
                
                Facades\Log::error('Simpan SPPA gagal', $return);
            }
```

Comment: You would have to share code with us in order for us to know how you can optimize your code.

Comment: sory i add my code. thanks for correction

Comment: I've looked at the code and I don't see anything wrong with it.  Check the queries that are getting run by the ORM and see if they indeed take ~1 second to run manually via the Management Studio or whatever app you are using to interface with the database.  If they are indeed slow, you can use [EXPLAIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) to figure out why. If the queries are fast, then the problem is elsewhere.  Could be the network between dev and database, a VM shared folder or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, when i add index in field that used for check duplicate data, the proccess is faster. Now one hit takes a second or less.